# How to populate data in a new field, from existing records

Tags: administration

I have a text field 'C' which is updated using a workflow. The field concatenates values of two fields, say 'A' and 'B', to prevent any duplicates. How can I populate this field 'C' with existing records that I already have.

Answer (score 4):

I dont really think you need a trigger here as you already admit that you have a workflow that will perform this action moving forward.  If you didnt already have a workflow in place, then yes, a trigger would be the way to go, but since this is just a one time update, you can simply run some code in execute anonymous.  If you have a full sandbox, you can test in there prior to production to ensure it has the desired outcome.  If this becomes something you want to do regularly, you can easily make this a batch and/or scheduled job.

Something like this should work

```
list<your_object__c> myList = [Select Id, Name, A, B, C From your_object__c Where C = null || C = ''];
for(your_object__c o : myList){
     o.C = o.A + ' ' + o.B;
}
update myList;
```

Answer (score 0):

**The best way to do this is via a trigger:**

1. Write a trigger on update on that object.
2. Check for every record if C is empty, concatenate A & B and do an update on C for every record.
3. Export all the Ids of that object in an excel file - just the ids.
4. Run the data loader and do the update on that object using that excel file.

This will work perfectly fine.

> **Note: Please bulkify that trigger otherwise it might not work, and
>    depending on the # of records you have select the batch size in the
>   data loader's settings.**

Comment: Hi **subodhbahl** is your process not complete at step 2? WHy would you export the id and bring it back in?

Comment: @Bartley, Step 2 is the code for the trigger which does the following: for (object o : listABC){ if(o.C__c != null { //Concat the 2 fields}}

And once you do this, and then do an update the trigger will fire for every record you have in the csv. The purpose of this is if you miss any records or have any data issues, you can re run the dataloader and fix those.

Comment: This would only work on objects which get updated (would not set values in old records, as the question asks)

Comment: @NathanWallace It will set the values in any record that you export via the csv. So, export the records as needed, and update. Records will get updated, I have done it in the past.